# Core Data: Subquery Performance Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, subquery, aggregate-functions

I've been trying to see if there is any way I can improve on the performance of the following Predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"A=%@ and SUBQUERY($self.words,$k,$k.keyword IN %@).@count==%d", 
  <value for A>, 
  keywordList, 
  [keywordList count]];
```

What I'm trying to do is return all the records of A that have keywords that are ALL contained in the supplied array (keywordList).  I have a small database of about 2000 records.  However, the keywords for each Entity ranges from 40-300 keywords. The keywords are represented as a to-Many relationship  from A to an entity called Keywords.  The above query works but takes about 7 seconds to run on my iPhone4.  I want to see what I can do to shrink that down to a sub-second response.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: If you just query for the keywords for a given A how is performance then? I mean, can you rewrite the predicate to do the subquery as the main query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are approaching the problem backwards. If you have the keywords, you should search for the `Keyword` objects and then walk their `A` relationships to find the related `A` objects. <strike>Then check for overlap in the relationship sets.</strike>

So something like:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch=//...set up fetch
[fetch setEntity:Keyword_entity];
NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keyword IN %@",keywords];
[fetch setPredicate:p];
NSArray *fetchedObj=//... execute fetch

NSMutableSet *inCommon=[NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:[fetchedObjs count]];
for (NSManagedObject *mo in fetchedObjs){
  if ([inCommon count]==0){
    [inCommon addObjects:[mo valueForKey:@"aRelationshipName"]];
  }else{
    [inCommon intersectSet:[mo valueForKey:@"aRelationshipName"]];
  }
}
```

... `inCommon` would then contain a set of all unique `A` objects that shared all the keywords.

Update:

From OP author:

> This doesn't quite solve the problem
>   as the results that come back from
>   intersection of the fetchedObjs is not
>   correct. It doesn't guarantee that all
>   the 'A' objects contain all the
>   supplied keywords.

Okay, lets take another tack. Assuming you have a data model that looks something like this:

```
A {
    keywords<<-->>Keyword.as
}

Keyword{
    keyword:string
    as<<-->>A.keywords
}
```

Then something like this should work:

```
NSFetchRequest *keyWordFetch=//...set up fetch
[keyWordFetch setEntity:Keyword_entity];
NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keyword IN %@",keywords];
[keyWordFetch setPredicate:p];
NSArray *fetchedKeywords=//... execute keyWordFetch


NSFetchRequest *entityAFetch=//...set up fetch
[entityAFetch setEntity:A_entity];
NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL keywords IN %@", fetchedKeywords);
[entityAFetch setPredicate:pred];
NSArray *fetchedAs=//... execute fetch
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your initial comment got me thinking.  I ended up remodeling my design.  My search is now a multipass search.  The first scans a normalized table of keywords and generates a Set of record ids that match to 'A' objects.  The second pass queries for all 'A' objects with ids in the set from the first request.

Comment: The search is now sub-second on my iPhone4.  Thanks for the help!  I ended up removing the relationship between A and the keywords.  This  also solved another issue for me which was the loading.  Without having to model the relationship the load time  was reduced dramatically.

Comment: Update to my current situation...  For those who might be interested or can provide a possible improvement..   My Model now looks like so:
Keywords and A are not connnected via a relationship any longer.  It seems that when I import the data using relationships as I import A objects, the time to import increases significantly.  
Each Keyword entity has the keyword and a string that contains all the A record identifiers associated with the keyword separated by "^" sign.  I refrained from storing them as a Set since i don't plan on searching based on recordid.

Comment: I now do a two pass search.
1) get all the Keyword objects matching the keywords passed in as input to the search.  create a set containing the intersection of all the record ids from this search
2) query A for all the entities in the set from 1

there are about 18k keywords with each keyword having roughly 11 A objects they are related to.  The max being 156. 

this makes my searches at most to take about .8 seconds, a huge improvement over what I had before where searches could take up to 8 seconds

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite solve the problem as the results that come back from intersection of the fetchedObjs is not correct.  It doesn't guarantee that all the 'A' objects contain all the supplied keywords.  In fact, what comes back is an empty list and the entire process actually takes longer.

Something must be wrong with my model or the previous answer.  I'm not getting the results I'm expecting.  One alternative to returning a list of 'A' would be to return a list of ManagedObjectIDs of 'A'.  [mo valueForKey: (NSString *)] returns the object of the relationship.

Note: I originally posted this question anonymously thinking I was logged in, so i can't seem to comment on anybody's answer.

Comment: I merged your other account into your registered one so you can edit the question and leave comments.  Please delete this answer once you're done.  Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow.